# Всплывающая корзина для Битрикс Pop-Up Cart Bitrix

Tags: битрикс, всплывающее-окно, popup, корзина, cart

Почему-то гугл девственно пуст на запрос bitrix popup cart
Подскажите направление мыслей, хочу сделать корзину поп-ап, т.е. добавляю товар в корзину (и со страницы категории, и со страницы товара) - выскакивает поп-ап, в котором вся корзина - товары, цена, кол-во, кол-во можно менять? Версия 15.

**Пока что наметил два пути:**
1. Формировать отдельным файлом список товаров в корзине и в попап затаскивать через

```
 $.getJSON('/include/какой-то_файл.php', {...}
```

Тут неясен вопрос с обновлением кол-ва товаров.

2. Делать похожий запрос, но уже на страницу корзины и туда же отправлять данные в случае смены количества и тут же опять получать обновленную корзину, карусель какая-то))))
   **Есть ли ТРЕТИЙ вариант?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно popup или modal?
Если просто попап, то просто создаете страницу с компонентом корзины (но без стандартного header&footer). В попапе и выведется стандартная корзина битрикса.
Если же нужно через ajax выводить окно в теле текущей страницы, я бы реализовал это через API корзины (http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/sale/classes/csalebasket/index.php ), дергая данные json-ом.

Comment: а в чем разница попап-модал? я считал, что одно и тоже с визуальной точки зрения, не?

Comment: Попап технически - это новое окно браузера. Модал на CSS - блок в теле текущей страницы. Во всяком случае, в классическом понимании этого дела.

Comment: Fly корзина нужна в итоге, как вывести тут же на странице список товаров (которые уже в корзине) и кнопки больше-меньше?

Comment: Да, надо через ajax вывести корзину на странице каталога